# Outlook VSTO set SendUsingAccount only works once

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to have my add-in set the "From" account to my default account when I'm sending an email from another "Public" account. It works fine the first time I start a new email, but after that, it no longer works. Here's my simplified code. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Account defaultAcct = null;
 
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector += new InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);

        Accounts accounts = Application.Session.Accounts;
        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {
            var displayName = account.DisplayName;
            if(displayName.Contains("example.com"))
            {
                defaultAcct = account;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Inspector Inspector)
    {
        if (Inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
        {
            MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;

            if (mailItem.Sent == false)
            {
                if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount != null)
                {
                    if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName == "Public")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("In Public, set from to: " + defaultAcct.DisplayName); // shows every time
                        mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct; // Only gets set the first time
                    }
                }

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
For testing, I changed my code to this.
The subject gets set as expected every time, but the SendUsingAccount only gets set the first time.

```
void Inspectors_NewInspector(Inspector Inspector)
{
    if (Inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
    {
        MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
        mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct;
        mailItem.Subject = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the code sits in a VSTO Smart doc...but what does it have to w/vsto? Have you attempted to mock the values and send in a unit test?

Comment: Is the event fired the second or third time? Have you tried setting a breakpoint when debugging?

Comment: Yes the event is fired every time & yes the breakpoint works inside the event. Even if I change the code to:
`if (mailItem.Sent == false)
{
   mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct;
}`
It still only sets the From the first time.

Comment: I've updated the original question with more info.

Comment: Have you tried handling the `Activate` event and get the `CurrentItem` property and other item-specific data there?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, in the code you check the `SendUsingAccount` property value whether it is `null` or not:

```
if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount != null)
{
   if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName == "Public")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("In Public, set from to: " + defaultAcct.DisplayName); // shows every time
      mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct; // Only gets set the first time
    }
}
```

If the property was set once, your code will not be working any longer. For example, a user may change the value on the Outlook UI - in that case your code is not valid. I'd suggest handling these two cases separately, for example:

```
if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount != null && mailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName == "Public")
{
      MessageBox.Show("In Public, set from to: " + defaultAcct.DisplayName); // shows every time
      mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct; // Only gets set the first time
}
else
{
     mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct; // set to the default
}
```

**Second**, you need to declare the source object (`inspectors`) at the class level if you want to continue receiving events:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Account defaultAcct = null;
    private Inspectors inspectors = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
```

**Third**, another aspect is the `NewInspector` event handler. I'd suggest waiting for the first [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event and only then access the *item* properties. The item may not be initialized yet at that stage.

Comment: The if and else are doing the something, so mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct is always called. But, I tried your && condition and it still doesn't work after the first new window. The Inspectors is at the class level, I just missed it when I cut down the sample code. Do you have an example of waiting for the active event?

Comment: Just subscribe to the `Activate` event in the `NewInspector` event handler. When it is fired you can get the item instance and do the rest. See [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `SendUsingAccount` on a new message might be null if the default account is to be used, so your check must be

```
if (mailItem.SendUsingAccount == null || !mailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName.Contains("example.com"))
{
    mailItem.SendUsingAccount = defaultAcct; 
}
```